# Вылазеет ошибка Что делать'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'midtop'

Tags: python

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

W = 800
H = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font_path = 'mario_font.ttf'
font_large = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 48)
font_small = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 24)

game_over = False
retry_text = font_small.render('Нажмите любую клавишу', True, (255, 255, 255))
retry_rect = retry_text.get_rect()
retry_text.midtop = (W // 2, H // 2)

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.tupe == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    clock.tick(FPS)

    screen.fill((92, 148, 252))

    pygame.display.flip()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
retry_text = font_small.render('Нажмите любую клавишу', True, (255, 255, 255))
retry_rect = retry_text.get_rect()
      ^^^^              ^^^^^^^^
retry_text.midtop = (W // 2, H // 2)
      ^^^^
```

`midtop` - это свойство `Rect`, вы его положили строкой выше в переменную `retry_rect`, но вы берёте `midtop` от `Surface` вместо этого, которая у вас в `retry_text`. Нужно просто взять свойство `midtop` от правильной переменной:

```
retry_rect.midtop = (W // 2, H // 2)
```